# Get current time with/in milliseconds from OS X command line

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line

I'm trying to get the current time from OS X command line to work with in AppleScript to output the elapsed time.

Currently I'm using this script:

```
set timea to do shell script "date +%s"
##something is executed
set timeb to do shell script "date +%s"
set runningtime to timeb - timea
```

But it is too unprecised, **so I'm looking for a way how to get the elapsed precisely with milliseconds** or somethin.

Thanks.
:)

Comment: You'll likely want to script your timing in bash (faster to execute) than AppleScript - you could use the `gdate` command or `logger` to dump the timing to a file for analysis external to the script if desired...